Using "each" after a plural subject
"A, B, and C each take one input"
versus
"A, B, and C each takes one input"
which is correct?

It uses the plural verb. You can see it more obviously if you reword slightly:

A, B, and C take one input apiece.

"each" and "apiece" are modifiers that indicate that "one input" applies separately to each item, but it doesn't change the plural nature of the sentence subject.

Correct:

Each of A, B, and C takes one input
A, B, and C take one input each
A, B, and C each take one input

Wrong:

Each of A, B, and C take one input
A, B, and C takes one input each
A, B, and C each takes one input

